# Why doesn't this if/else run before the other prompts

Tags: javascript

```
var password = prompt('Please enter your password.');
if (password!=="cat" && password!=="cow") {
console.log(password);
location.assign("http://www.google.com")
}


//The rest of prompts
var age = prompt("What is your age?");
var name = prompt('What is your name?');
var homeTown = prompt('Where are you from?');
var favoritDog = prompt("What's your favorite dog?");
```

So that's my code, (I'm a beginner and just messing around with concepts), if the incorrect password is put in, shouldn't it redirect me to google right away? Because when I run that code, it gives me all the prompts first before the redirect. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because doing `location.assign` will not stop the execution of JavaScript, it will keep going. It will do the location assignment after the sequential JavaScript finishes. Since `prompt` blocks the current execution, for it to finish it will need to go through the prompts. To prevent it simply add your prompts to an `else`:

```
var password = prompt('Please enter your password.');
if (password!=="cat" && password!=="cow") {
    console.log(password);
    location.assign("http://www.google.com")
} else {
    //The rest of prompts
    var age = prompt("What is your age?");
    var name = prompt('What is your name?');
    var homeTown = prompt('Where are you from?');
    var favoritDog = prompt("What's your favorite dog?");
}
```

Comment: So do prompts have priority over certain things on javascript?

Comment: It blocks execution, but other than that it's not a priority thing. It's just `location.assign` does not happen until after the JavaScript is sequenced and executed through. You can think of it like it adds that to a queue, and then runs that once everything is done. For example you could replace the `prompt` with `console.log()` and you will still see the console show those items.

Comment: Why doesn't the if statement block execution since it's being satisfied? Why do the prompts have to run before the if/elses? I guess I'm just not understanding why the prompts qualify to go first

Comment: @AnthonyDeGennaro JavaScript executes sequentially line-by-line. The `prompts` are not running before the `if` (notice that the `console.log(password)` is executing first). It's just that `location.assign("http://www.google.com")` basically means in laymans terms that JavaScript will *"make a note to do that after it's done with the rest of the JS"*.

Comment: Does the "make note to do after" happen just for locations? Or just for location.assign's? Who gets that and who doesn't? Btw I really appreciate all the help

Comment: @AnthonyDeGennaro It's just that the function isn't blocking, and as such the rest of the JavaScript keeps running. That's just a way of thinking about it, basically though while the new page is loading the rest of the JavaScript keeps running, it doesn't stop the JS.